# Facebook Integration with in Android

Tags: android, facebook

Android 2.3.3

This is the first time i am integrating Facebook in Android. I am having trouble, on the very first step - importing Facebook SDK.

My requirement is to allow people post on my wall, using the application..

Here is what I have done :::

1. Downloaded SDK from this link ::: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk
2. Unzipped it and tried to import it in my workspace. Please refer to the images below...

[image]

I am pretty much confident, that I am doing something wrong. I am not sure, what it is. can some one point me where I am going wrong?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is copy "facebook" folder from your downloaded facebook-sdk. And paste it into the workspace folder where you create and store android apps. Now, in eclipse import "facebook" into eclipse. Now create your own project and in properties of your project, add "facebook" as library and that's it...

Comment: Yeah that's what I did.. I copied it into the folder and tried to import it into the workspace... But when I try to import facebook, it shows so many libraries to import.. I tried importing the one that says "FacebookSDK", but it has errors, with fragments

Comment: you better clean up yor project and try again. I wad facing the same problem...

Comment: cleaned the project.. no use.. still getting the errors

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/android/downloads/

Download version 3.0.1 or 3.0.2 and try again...

Comment: I have the FacebookSDk without errors now.. is it the one that I should be using? and why is it there are so many of those libraries in the zip file?

Comment: yes, you should use the new one...

Answer (score 1):

Following are the steps to include Facebook SDK into android project:

1) Download the Facebook SDK from the https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/ 
   and extract it to local drive.

2) Import "facebook" as a android project into your Eclipse, this is your Facebook SDK, and You have to reference it to your android project.

3) Now create your android project.

4) Right click on it, go to Properties-->android and Add the "facebook "Library as a reference to your project. click Apply.

Check the video link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-vNi1W4fco